# Google Charts Does not render for a scatter plot with multiple colors

Tags: html, google-visualization

I am plotting up data in Google Charts and continue to have trouble rendering my HTML. I could sure use a second pair of eyes to check if there is anything obviously wrong with the code below.  The data has three columns, each of which is meant to be plotted a different color.

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
    // draws it.
    function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()({
            [['x','Virg','Set','Versi'],
            [1.0,null,null,1.0],
            [2.0,null,2.0,null],
            [3.0,3.0,null,null]]

    });

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
      title: "Edgar Anderson's Iris Data Set",
      hAxis: {title: 'Petal Length', minValue: 0, maxValue: 7},
      vAxis: {title: 'Petal Width', minValue: 0, maxValue: 2.5},
      legend: ''
      //series:{
      //      0: { pointShape: 'circle' },
      //      1: {pointShape: 'triangle'},
      //      2: { pointShape: 'square'}
      //   }
        };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call to `arrayToDataTable()` is wrong. Instead of

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()({
        [['x','Virg','Set','Versi'],
        [1.0,null,null,1.0],
        [2.0,null,2.0,null],
        [3.0,3.0,null,null]]

});
```

you have to use

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['x','Virg','Set','Versi'],
        [1.0,null,null,1.0],
        [2.0,null,2.0,null],
        [3.0,3.0,null,null]
]);
```

Instead of an object of array you have to provide an array of arrays. And unnecessary `()` deleted.

**Update: ** [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hidul/1/edit).

Comment: Thanks. I removed the () but it still does not render. Might there be a different formatting issue, I wonder?

Comment: It is not just `()`. You have to remove also starting { and ending }. See link to example at jsbin.

Comment: Thanks again Anto. I copied and pasted from jsbin and it worked. But even making the changes you suggested, I could not get my original code to work. Thanks again!